# 3021:The Basket format is invalid

Tags: opayo

Just trying to spot what is invalid with my basket XML.. anyone got any ideas?

This gets a response of "3021:The Basket format is invalid"

```
<basket>
  <item>
    <description>A Product</description>
    <productSKU>2</productSKU>
    <quantity>2</quantity>
    <unitNetAmount>49.00</unitNetAmount>
    <unitTaxAmount>9.80</unitTaxAmount>
    <unitGrossAmount>58.80</unitGrossAmount>
    <totalGrossAmount>117.60</totalGrossAmount>
  </item>
</basket>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried this with my Server integration. Had to change 'productSKU' to 'productSku' to get it working.

Looks like this an error in the documentation.

Comment: Hi Rik, Thank you! you are correct, I have spoken to SagePay & they have confirmed it is an error in the documentation.. also TotalGrossAmount is also incorrect.. should be as above totalGrossAmount.